# Some images showing in React Native iOS emulator and others not?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native

I am adding Images to my React Native app, but some images are not showing up...
Is there a reason for this? Like is there a max size that React Native Images can handle? here is what I'm doing:

```
import assets from '../../assets';
...
render() {
 return 
        <View style={styles.imageView}>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={assets.images.myImage}
          />
        </View>
 
}
```

For reference `styles.image` looks like this:

```
image: {
  height: 170,
  width: 170,
}
```

I'm pretty sure my syntax is all correct (I mean, it is rendering some images, but not others). What is the problem? Anything helps. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly an issue with file types? Can you create an Expo snack that reproduces your issue? https://expo.io/

Comment: @DrewReese definitely not a file type issue. I have used a .png in another screen and it works fine.

Comment: Is it always the same images not loading? What debugging steps have you taken? Are there any errors?

Comment: I've solved the issue:
apparently to use a static file (such as an image) it must be declared as such:
`var myImage = require ('../../assets/images/myImage.png');` and then you can use `myImage` in your component.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you though for reminding me to debug thoroughly!